# Can I position an element at the bottom right corner of a flexible image with pure CSS?

Tags: html, css

The overlay image in the example below is supposed to stay at the same location relative to the larger image independent of the size of the container.

I added 2 examples below of the "img_overlay" CSS module, one where it is inside a portrait test container (green), and another inside a green landscape container. It works fine for portrait, but not for landscape, because the "img_overlay__container" (red) extends to the whole width of the parent container instead of being limited to the width of the black image. If the red container would be as wide as the black image then everything would be OK.

I can make it work for landscape too with a simple inline-block, but then it breaks for portrait.

Mind that the image should be flexible, expanding and shrinking according to the available space, up to its natural size, so no fixed size solutions please. And the overlay image should retain its size ratio in relation to the black image (25% of the black image), so that it looks the same independent of screen size.

I should add that I am testing on Chrome Version 59.0.3071.115 (Official Build)
 (64-bit)

Am I missing something or is it simply not possible with current CSS3?

**Edit** (14/07/2017): I made the containers resizable so its easier to test.
https://jsfiddle.net/rvmxpwq1/3/

```js
$( ".test" ).resizable();
```

```css
body {
 margin-bottom: 100vh;
}

.img_overlay {
    display: inline-flex;
    max-height: 100%;
}

.img_overlay__container {
    position: relative;
    background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}

.img_overlay__img {
    border-radius: 50%;
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}

.img_overlay__overlay {
    border-radius: 50%;
    max-width: 25%;
   max-height: 25%;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
}

.test {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: rgb(0, 255, 0);
    border: 3px solid rgb(0, 255, 0);
}

.test--1 {
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
}

.test--2 {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
}

.test--3 {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
Portrait container (300x200): <strong>works</strong>, this is how it should always look at any container size.
<div class="test test--1">
    <div class="img_overlay">
        <div class="img_overlay__container">
            <img class="img_overlay__img" src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/000/ffffff.jpg&text=Image">
            <img class="img_overlay__overlay" src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/0000ff/ffffff.jpg&text=Overlay">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<br> Landscape container (200x300): <strong>does not work</strong>, because the overlay is not next to the image.
<div class="test test--2">
    <div class="img_overlay">
        <div class="img_overlay__container">
            <img class="img_overlay__img" src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/000/ffffff.jpg&text=Image">
            <img class="img_overlay__overlay" src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/0000ff/ffffff.jpg&text=Overlay">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<br> Large container (500x500): <strong>works</strong>, the images are not enlarged above their natural size.
<div class="test test--3">
    <div class="img_overlay">
        <div class="img_overlay__container">
            <img class="img_overlay__img" src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/000/ffffff.jpg&text=Image">
            <img class="img_overlay__overlay" src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/0000ff/ffffff.jpg&text=Overlay">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is. Does your demo show an overlay out of position? If so, where do you want the overlay instead? If not, what do we need to do to reproduce the problem? In both boxes, as far as I can tell, the overlay is in the center of the larger image, and there is an image above a smaller image in the bottom right.

Comment: @Michael Coker I edited the question with more details.
In the code snippet you see 2 examples of the "img_overlay" CSS module, one where it is inside a green portrait container, and another inside a green landscape container. It works fine for portrait, but not for landscape, because the red "img_overlay__container" extends to the whole width of the parent container instead of being limited to the width of the image. This causes the overlay to shift to the right instead of staying in the bottom right corner of the image.

Comment: Ah... I just opened it in Firefox vs Chrome and it's completely different. What browser are you using?

Comment: @Michael Coker Chrome 59, but I also tested now in Firefox 54 and it looks the same. What version of Firefox did you use?

Answer (score 2):

How about now?

here is a fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/f9e2gkpk/5/

```css
.wrapper{
 max-height: 100%;
 max-width: 100%;  
}
.img_overlay {
 display: inline-flex;
 max-height: 100%;
}
.img_overlay__container {
 position: relative;
 background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0)
}
.img_overlay__img {
 border-radius: 50%;
 max-height: 100vh;
 max-width: 100%;
}
.img_overlay__overlay {
 border-radius: 50%;
 width: 25%;
 position: absolute;
 right: 0px;
 bottom: 0px;
}
.test {
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
 background-color: rgb(0, 255, 0);
 border: 3px solid rgb(0, 255, 0);
 height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="test test--2">
  <div class="img_overlay">
    <div class="img_overlay__container">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <img class="img_overlay__img" src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/000/ffffff.jpg&text=Image">
        <img class="img_overlay__overlay" src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/0000ff/ffffff.jpg&text=Overlay">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No, this is exactly what I want to avoid. The overlay should always stay right next to the Image. In the code snippet I provided, the portrait version is the one that works correctly, the landscape version is not (because the overlay moves away from the image).
Its too bad that Stack overflow does not have a way to easily resize the code snippet result to see how the images behave at different sizes. It would be useful especially for responsive CSS.

Comment: I improved my code snippet to make what I mean a bit clearer.

Comment: I see you have updated your code, and it looks much better. Now the overlay stays where it should in both landscape and portrait.
But sadly your solution only works if the container takes up the whole window height. If I set it to 500px height and 300px width it still breaks. But good try, thank you.

Comment: I updated the code in my question to make the containers resizable. This should make it much easier to test.